# White stuff on the Japanease Honeysuckle

Tags: diagnosis, outdoor, honeysuckle

Some white stuff is growing on my honeysuckle, tried looking it up online but I can't figure out what it us or how to cure it.

I'm hoping I can rely on your expertise, so any advise or suggestions are appreciated.

[image: Honeysuckle with white mould-like growth]
[image: Growth on stem close to new leaves]